# TargetSdkVersion 26 i got a main please clarify

Tags: android

Recently i got a mail from google to change the targetsdkversion to 26 or above 
but i have a question regarding this :

In my console i have around 50 android applications of which there are only 8 apps which are under production(in Live) and the rest apps i have already unpublished it and i will not use it any more (means  i will not publish those apps again) so my point is should i need to update the unpublished app to change the targetsdkversion to 26 or above as in mail i got if account has more than 20 apps which are not targetsdkverion 26 it may affect account 
please help me what to do

Comment: As far as I know they don't force you to update sdk until you start publishing new version.

Comment: you don't have to update unpublished apps until you are going to re-publish them because google won't let you re-publish them with older SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From android [docs](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk):

> Google Play will require that **new apps** target at least Android 8.0
>   (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that **app updates** target
>   Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018

You don't need to update your production apps until you actually wanted to release new update.

One more important fact:

> Configuring your app to target a recent API level ensures that users
>   can benefit from these improvements, while still allowing it to run on
>   older Android versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you will not publish those apps again then don't worry for account. Just update apps those are under production

Comment: You don't need to update your production apps. You can leave them as they are if you are not planning to release updates.